# Increasing the max execution time

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, mpm-event

Mine is Ubuntu 14 and I've enabled fpm-event with Apache.

`apachectl -V | grep -i mpm` shows:

```
Server MPM:     event
```

It seems those pages which take more than 30 seconds to execute I'm getting this error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Where should I change the configuration to increase it to day 45 seconds?

In the apache error log I can see:

> [Tue Apr 03 16:14:44.259133 2018] [fastcgi:error] [pid 28646:tid
>   140666243819264] [client 103.52.51.21:60161] FastCGI: comm with server
>   "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer:
>   http://www.example.com/google-analytics-charts/verify

Actually it is Drupal site which can be extremely slow.

Comment: What is your Timeout or ProxyTimeout directive set to?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this solution helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360922/increase-php-fpm-idle-timeout-setting

You can change idle-timeout in your apache config to extend it (cannot be 0):

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 1800 -pass-header Authorization
```